# Users should be able to drag the images and place it on image view in ios

Tags: drag-and-drop, imageview

I am creating an app in which users can design their own stage with the images present over there. I have created buttons as images, now I want some code which enables user to drag and drop the images(buttons) in the particular image view area.

Comment: I m new to development, this is my first project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this with tap gestures (e.g. tap first image view, tap on destination image view), but it's not very intuitive. Doing a proper drag-and-drop with a UIPanGestureRecognizer will be far more intuitive for your end user.

Technically, you're not dragging an image from the image view, but rather you'll actually be dragging the image view itself. (An image, itself, has no visual representation without an image view.) And when you let go, you'll animate the changing of the image view frames to complete the illusion.

If you had a NSArray of imageViews, you could add a gesture to their superview:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *imageViews;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

[self createImageViewArray];

UIPanGestureRecognizer *gesture = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self                                                                          action:@selector(handlePan:)];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:gesture];
}

- (void)createImageViewArray
{
self.imageViews = [NSMutableArray array];
}

- (void)handlePan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gesture
{
static UIImageView *draggedImage = nil;
static CGRect draggedImageOriginalFrame;

CGPoint location = [gesture locationInView:gesture.view];

if (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan)
{

    draggedImage = [self determineImageForLocation:location];

    if (draggedImage)
    {
        draggedImageOriginalFrame = draggedImage.frame;
        [draggedImage.superview bringSubviewToFront:draggedImage];
    }
}
else if (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged && draggedImage != nil)
{

    CGPoint translation = [gesture translationInView:gesture.view];
    CGRect frame = draggedImageOriginalFrame;
    frame.origin.x += translation.x;
    frame.origin.y += translation.y;
    draggedImage.frame = frame;
}
else if (draggedImage != nil && (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded ||
                                 gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateCancelled ||
                                 gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateFailed))
{

    UIImageView *droppedOver = nil;

    if (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
        droppedOver = [self draggedImageView:draggedImage toLocation:location];

    if (droppedOver == nil)
    {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25
                         animations:^{
                             draggedImage.frame = draggedImageOriginalFrame;
                         }];
    }
    else
    {
        [droppedOver.superview bringSubviewToFront:droppedOver];

        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25
                         animations:^{
                             draggedImage.frame = droppedOver.frame;
                             droppedOver.frame = draggedImageOriginalFrame;
                         }];
    }
  }
 }

- (UIImageView *)draggedImageView:(UIImageView *)draggedView toLocation:(CGPoint)location
{
   for (UIImageView *imageview in self.imageViews)
     if (CGRectContainsPoint(imageview.frame, location) && imageview != draggedView)
        return imageview;

 return nil;
}
- (UIImageView *)determineImageForLocation:(CGPoint)location
{
 return [self draggedImageView:nil toLocation:location];
}
```